# Regarding web site design with dynamic animation when page scroll down

Tags: jquery, html

Please view this website: http://www.invisionapp.com/

when your page scroll gradually then notice animation is playing on images but images were downloaded when page load. so i like to know how they design their web site this way.

suppose i want to design a web site which will have many images one after one but i want that when user scroll down then some kind of animation will start on those images.

please guide me how they develop that kind of web site with images like animation play when user scroll down the page. thanks

Comment: Google shall guide you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation you see are simply GIFs. If you open up the network inspector you can see that they are lazy loading the GIFs as the user scrolls.

One technique to achieve this is simply to hide the animation/GIF src in the DOM. `src` will have a dummy value while another attribute like `data-src` will hold the actual animation.

For ex: `<img src="dummy.png" data-src="cool-animation.gif">`

Once the user scrolls to a certain threshold it triggers the replacement of `src` with `data-src` and thus the animation "appears" to start.